# Raspberry Pi 3B cannot connect to wifi

Tags: wifi, pi-3b+, ubuntu, wireless

I was trying to connect to wifi from my RPI3 running Ubuntu 22 server.

This is my conf file

**/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf**

```
Ctrl_interface=DIR=/var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1
country=NL

network={
scan_ssid=1
ssid="JioFiber-Uc9FK"
psk="HPASSWORDp"
key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

Here is the truncated output of network scan.

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Output

```
Cell 03 - Address: 48:55:5E:72:97:82
                    Channel:2
                    Frequency:2.417 GHz (Channel 2)
                    Quality=60/70  Signal level=-50 dBm
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"JioFiber-Uc9FK"
                    Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s; 24 Mb/s
                              36 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                    Mode:Master
                    Extra:tsf=0000000000000000
                    Extra: Last beacon: 76ms ago
                    IE: Unknown: 000E4A696F46696265722D556339464B
                    IE: Unknown: 01088C129824B048606C
                    IE: Unknown: 030102
                    IE: Unknown: 2D1AAC0117FFFF000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: Unknown: 3D1602000400000000000000000000000000000000000000
                    IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                        Group Cipher : CCMP
                        Pairwise Ciphers (1) : CCMP
                        Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
```

Here is the output of ifconfig

```
hpoddar@raspberrypi:~$ ifconfig

wlan0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        ether b8:27:eb:52:e0:24  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

I did restart wpa_supplicant but I am still not connected to the wifi.

```
sudo systemctl restart wpa_supplicant
```

Output of **sudo raspi-config**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following answer and the blog helped me in solving my issue.

1. [failed-to-start-netplan-wpa-wlan0-sevice-unit-netplan-wpa-wlan0-service-not-found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1291424/failed-to-start-netplan-wpa-wlan0-sevice-unit-netplan-wpa-wlan0-service-not-fou)
2. [ubuntu-22-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line](https://linuxconfig.org/ubuntu-22-04-connect-to-wifi-from-command-line)

I'll add the same here as well.

1. First step is to open a command line terminal and identify the name of your wireless network interface. To do so execute:

```
$ ls /sys/class/net
eth0  lo  wlan0
```

2. Next, navigate to the /etc/netplan directory and locate the appropriate Netplan configuration files. The configuration file might have a name such as `01-network-manager-all.yaml` or `50-cloud-init.yaml`.

```
$ ls /etc/netplan/
50-cloud-init.yaml
```

3. Edit the Netplan configuration file with nano or your favorite text editor. You will have to open the file with root permissions.

```
$ sudo nano /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml
```

4. Copy and paste the following configuration stanza while replacing the SSID-NAME-HERE and PASSWORD-HERE text with your SSID network name and password:

```
wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "SSID-NAME-HERE":
                    password: "PASSWORD-HERE"
            dhcp4: true
```

5. Make sure that the wifis block is aligned with the above ethernets or version block if present. The entire configuration file may look similar to the one in my case:

```
GNU nano 6.2                                                                              /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml                                                                                        # This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
    wifis:
        wlan0:
            optional: true
            access-points:
                "JioFiber-Uc9FK":
                    password: "HbHRnE5Kymm2fDRp"
            dhcp4: true
```

6. Once ready, apply the changes and connect to your wireless interface by executing the bellow command:

```
$ sudo netplan apply
```

7. Alternatively, if you run into some issues execute:

```
$ sudo netplan --debug apply
```

8. If all went well you would be able to see your wireless adapter connected to the wireless network by executing the ip command:

```
ip a
```